# PHP - Fatal error: Call to undefined function

Tags: php

I am new to PHP, trying to work out why it is throwing this error when I am calling the checkFirst() and checkPass() in the html, code below - I have put ** around where the problem is accruing:

Error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function checkFirst() in C:\wamp\www\form\index.php on line 12

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <div class="signup_wrap">
            <div class="wrap"><label for="first">First Name:</label><input type="text" name="first" value=""></div>
            **<?php checkFirst($first); ?>**
            <div class="wrap"><label for="first">Last Name:</label> <input type="text" name="last" value=""></div>
            <div class="wrap"><label for="first">Password:</label> <input type="text" name="first_password" value=""></div>
            <div class="wrap"><label for="first">Confirm password:</label><input type="text" name="second_password" value=""></div>
            **<?php checkPass($password1, $password2);?>**
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

        </div>  

    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php 

$password1 = "";
$first = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $first = $_POST['first'];

    $password1 = $_POST['first_password'];
    $password2 = $_POST['second_password'];


    function checkFirst($first){
        if (empty($first)) {
                echo "Please enter text";
                return false;
            }
            return true;
    }


    function checkPass($password1, $password2){
        if (empty($password2)) {
                echo "Please enter text";
                return false;
            }   
            if ($password1 == $password2) {
                echo "Match";
                return true;
            } else {
                echo "False";
                return false;
            }
            return true;
    }

    function checkAll($first, $password1, $password2){
        if (checkPass($password1, $password2) && checkFirst($first)) {
            header("Location: http://www.trademe.co.nz");
            return true;
        } else {
            echo "Nope";
            return false;
        }
    }

    checkAll($first, $password1, $password2);


}

?>
```

Comment: function should be defined out of if condition

Comment: Place the functions outside of the IF otherwise you can´t access them unless you are in that very condition.

Comment: line 12 is the one that says "**<?php checkFirst($first); ?>**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining the functions inside the `if` condition for form submission.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

So the functions will have accessibility only within this `if` condition. You can place the functions outside the condition.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {    // start of condition
    $first = $_POST['first'];

    $password1 = $_POST['first_password'];
    $password2 = $_POST['second_password'];
    ----------------------
 }      // end of condition



/* Common Functions */

 function checkFirst($first){
        if (empty($first)) {
                echo "Please enter text";
                return false;
            }
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: Further, the functions are only accessible *after* being defined - even trying to access inside the `if` block but before definition will be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

function should be before if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <div class="signup_wrap">
                <div class="wrap"><label for="first">First Name:</label><input type="text" name="first" value=""></div>
                **<?php checkFirst($first); ?>**
                <div class="wrap"><label for="first">Last Name:</label> <input type="text" name="last" value=""></div>
                <div class="wrap"><label for="first">Password:</label> <input type="text" name="first_password" value=""></div>
                <div class="wrap"><label for="first">Confirm password:</label><input type="text" name="second_password" value=""></div>
                **<?php checkPass($password1, $password2);?>**
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

            </div>  

        </form>
    </body>
    </html>

    <?php 

    $password1 = "";
    $first = "";
      function checkFirst($first){
            if (empty($first)) {
                    echo "Please enter text";
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
        }
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $first = $_POST['first'];

        $password1 = $_POST['first_password'];
        $password2 = $_POST['second_password'];





        function checkPass($password1, $password2){
            if (empty($password2)) {
                    echo "Please enter text";
                    return false;
                }   
                if ($password1 == $password2) {
                    echo "Match";
                    return true;
                } else {
                    echo "False";
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
        }

        function checkAll($first, $password1, $password2){
            if (checkPass($password1, $password2) && checkFirst($first)) {
                header("Location: http://www.trademe.co.nz");
                return true;
            } else {
                echo "Nope";
                return false;
            }
        }

        checkAll($first, $password1, $password2);


    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code must be like this. Function should be defined out of the if condition.

```
<?php 

    $password1 = "";
    $first = "";

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $first = $_POST['first'];
        $password1 = $_POST['first_password'];
        $password2 = $_POST['second_password'];
        checkAll($first, $password1, $password2);
    }
    function checkFirst($first){
        if (empty($first)) {
                echo "Please enter text";
                return false;
            }
            return true;
    }


    function checkPass($password1, $password2){
        if (empty($password2)) {
                echo "Please enter text";
                return false;
            }   
            if ($password1 == $password2) {
                echo "Match";
                return true;
            } else {
                echo "False";
                return false;
            }
            return true;
    }
    function checkAll($first, $password1, $password2){
        if (checkPass($password1, $password2) && checkFirst($first)) {
            header("Location: http://www.trademe.co.nz");
            return true;
        } else {
            echo "Nope";
            return false;
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update last function like this

```
function checkAll($first, $password1, $password2){
    $chekPass = checkPass($password1, $password2);
    $chekFirst = checkFirst($first);
    if ( $checkPass && $checkFirst ) {
        header("Location: http://www.trademe.co.nz");
        return true;
    } else {
        echo "Nope";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're defining the functions inside the `if` block, they only get defined after testing that condition and it's true. You're trying to call the functions before the `if` test, so the functions haven't been defined yet.

Normally you should define functions at the top-level of the script, then they can be used from anywhere in the script, because they're not dependent on a condition.